# Show that there is a ﬁxed $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all $s \in I, \gamma(s)=\beta(s)+p$.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

Suppose that $\beta,\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^3$ are two unit speed smooth curves. Suppose that the curvatures and tortions are everywhere positive, and that $B_\beta(s)= B_\gamma(s)$ for all $s\in I$. Show that there is a ﬁxed $p \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $\gamma(s)= \beta(s)+p$ ,for all $s \in I,.$

Comment: I have deleted the wrong tags (algebraic geometry, algebraic curves).

Comment: What does the notation $B_\beta$ mean here? The binormal vector? This seems to be related to the [main theorem of curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Main_theorem_of_curve_theory).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes I think it is binormal vectors of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ resp. I guess this means that one is the same as the other with a translation? but how do we show this? do we use the curvatures and tortions somehow?

Comment: @jandrew please advice

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate the given equation and use the Frenet equations repeatedly to deduce that the torsions and principal normals agree, then curvatures and tangents. Finally, use the Fundamental Theorem of curve theory mentioned above.